# HANA 'Order By' binary sort for strings

Tags: sql, hana

SAP HANA gives bad results when ordering by a string, as it seems to be sorted according to the Hex codes of each character?
German special characters like "Ö" come after Z (should be after O) like this.

**list_of_names**

```
-Oname
-Öname
-Zname
```

```
SELECT name
FROM list_of_names
ORDER BY name
```

==> Oname, Zname, Öname

Is there any way to make HANA sort text the right way (like MSSQL's 'COLLATE')?

Comment: Is your question about SQL in HANA, or Open SQL inside ABAP?

Answer (score 5):

There is an [older answer to this in SAP‘s Q&A](https://answers.sap.com/questions/606548/orderby-with-collation-in-sap-hana.html):

`... ORDER BY name ASC with parameters('LOCALE' = 'de');`

Where „de“ is an ISO language code.

Answer (score 0):

Characterlike components are sorted by default according to their binary representation (code page). Using ABAP, you could use the [SORT](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapsort_extract.htm) function to order your table the correct way.

```
SORT itab AS TEXT
```